# configure Valgrind plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, valgrind

I have installed valgrind plugin in Jenkins.
I just want to trigger my binary(of a simple C program ) with valgrind trough jenkins(valgrind plugin)

Under Build->Run Valgrind Options
I have given Working Directory as directory of my executable.
executable Include pattern as quick*  (quick is my executable name)

When I run the build the following is the console output.

```
Building in workspace /home/iptv/.jenkins/jobs/testVal/workspace
[VAlgrind] Error, java.lang.NullPointerException: null
Build step 'Run Valgring' marked build as failure
Finished: Failure
```

Is ther some where we need to declare environment variables ${PROGRAM_NAME} and ${PROGRAM_DIR}
Am I missing something to configure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I get the same error